# How to fill missing facts in the drools memory at runtime?

Tags: drools, rule-engine

Lets say we have a rule as follows:-

```
rule "Compute on multiple values"
when
     val1: Value(key == "val1")
     val2: Value(key == "val2")
     val3: Value(key == "val3")
then 
     Value total = val1.add(val2).add(val3)
end
```

Value is a pojo entity having following members :-

```
String key;
BigDecimal value;
```

Now, in the working memory we may get both the facts any number of the facts.

How do I ensure at runtime that the missing facts are treated with alteast 0 as a value before rules are executed?

Comment: If facts are missing they cannot participate in rule firing, and so the rule will not be fired. If you need to supply a fact with default values, write a rule that creates and inserts it.

Comment: what do you mean with "the missing facts"?